# Style format on button first letters

Tags: c#, xaml, format

Would like to set the first 3 letters of a button to be bold and underlined.

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText}"/>
```

Would you know how to do this? Obviously not with a string format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think there is no way you can do this entirely in XAML but with a little help from C# it is possible. Here is how I would do it:

Firs I created a Class called DummyData with a property Text which then I divide this property in two separate properties. First one contains only the first 3 letters of my Text and the other one contains the rest:

```
public DummyData TestData { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{

    TestData = new DummyData() { Text = "This is a test data." };

    InitializeComponent();
}

public class DummyData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string FirstThreeLetters
    {
        get
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            {
                result = Text.Substring(0, 3);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public string RestOfTheText
    {
        get
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            {
                result = Text.Substring(3);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we will unite these properties in XAML like this:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="200" Height="100">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding TestData.FirstThreeLetters, Mode=OneWay}" /><Run Text="{Binding TestData.RestOfTheText, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Pay attention to DataContext because that's how I bind the data from my code-behind. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Hasan. Thanks a lot, it's a great solution. I've implemented it though have an issue on the display, there is some space between the first part of the word ans the last part. Can't figure out why (and no margin found snopping it)

Comment: Glad you found it helpful could you edit your answer and share your code so I can take a look on what's happening. Just try to not have space between runs and put them in single line if this does not work share your code please :).

Comment: That fixes it, thank you!
Issue now is the base style of the button is gone (colors when enabled/disabled are not the same)

Comment: Note: I was able to do the same with a WrapPanel with TexBlocks inside. No need in that case to put these two blocks on the same line like the Runs. Not fixing the style though..

Comment: In that case you have to share your code with your styles in order to get a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry cannot, it's actually inheriting from a third-party style I don't know the details of. My guess is that the style defines the text to be in a given color on a given tag, and that tag isn't what I use here.

Comment: There is no way to know that unless you don't have a documentation or something.

Comment: Yes no worries, will figure out. Marked the answer as the good one. thanks again for the help!